# MVC2 + ASP.NET 4.0 + IIS6 + extensionless URLS, no longer need wildcard mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, isapi, wildcard-mapping

I noticed that asp.net 4.0 now installs a top-level isapi plugin (in iis6), such that it can inspect every request coming to the server. Should this now allow us to run MVC applications with extensionless URLS and have the aspnet isapi process them correctly without requiring the wildcard mapping (and avoid the performance penalties associated)? I havent found anything written about this yet, and havent had time to investigate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tmarq/how-to-disable-the-asp-net-v4-0-extensionless-url-feature-on-iis-6-0)

appears that there are new features in asp.net 4.0 that enable extensionless urls. I need to do more research on this to find out how to utilize it.

Basically it appends /eurl.axd/GUID to each routed request, which then gets passed to aspnet_isapi.dll to be processed. the eurl.axd is then removed at this point.

The problems Im having is how these interact between my Ionics rewriter IIRF software and this new .net rewriting... they seem to be interfereing with each other at times.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET 4.0 installs the `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll` ISAPI filter in order to map incoming request to the new CLR, but this filter is not registered as wildcard mapping but is associated only with known extensions. It does not intercept every incoming request. If you want to have extensionless urls you will need to perform the [same steps](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) as for ASP.NET 2.0 but use the new ISAPI filter instead.

Comment: Darin, this is different from the Isapi filter I am seeing, however I think the one I see is only used for "extensionless url's"... and not really what I'm after. 
What I'm seeing is mapped to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dllI suspect this is intalled in iis6 to try to emulate some missing iis7 functionality.  Any ideas?